# Issues Using *ngFor on Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'd like to show items from an array in a modal that displays after a button click inside a table.

HTML for the button:

```
<td class="col-xs-1 ">
  <button (click)="unshippedMaterialModalShow()">Show</button>
</td>
```

TS for the button:

```
  unshippedMaterialModalShow() {
    const modalContainer: any = document.getElementById('self-built-modal');
    modalContainer.style.display='block';
}
```

HTML for the modal:

```
<div
 id="self-built-modal"
 tabindex="-1"
 role="dialog"
 aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
 aria-hidden="true"
 onload="loadUnshippedMaterial(item.wtNumber)"
 >
 <div *ngFor="let item of dataModel.unshippedItems; let i = index">{{item.location}}</div>
 <div id="overlay"></div>
 <div id="modal-contents">
   <div id="modal-header">

      <button
        id="unshipped-modal-close"
        type="button"
        (click)="unshippedMaterialModalHide()"
        aria-label="Close"
      >
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <hr>
      Unshipped Material Modal
       {{item.wtNumber}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my DataModel component:

```
    customer: string;
    address: string;
    workPerformed: string;
    assignedTo: string;
    statusCode: string;
    steps: Array<any> = [];
    wts: Array<any> = [];
    subdivisions: Array<any> = [];
    orders: Array<any> = [];
    ordersLM: Array<any> = [];
    tracking: string;
    loaded: Array<any> = [];
    loadtech: Array<any> = [];
    salesorder: string;
    statusCodes: string;
    techid: string;
    statuscomment: string;
    newtracking: string;
    finaltracking: string;
    leadmanReport: Array<any> = [];
    redFlag: string;
    miscTech: Array<any> = [];
    unshippedItems: Array<any> = [];
}
```

Any code that I put inside of the `div` with the `*ngFor` statement doesn't show up on the modal. If I move it to be the parent container then I get a separate error: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OvbX7Z8rbsy0Brdk1ey_SYNmbluO-ghl/view?usp=sharing

I have another modal on the page that uses an `*ngFor` statement that displays the information it's supposed to correctly but I was unsure if it affected this modal or not.

I'm not that familiar with Angular so I'm unsure if I'm doing anything incorrectly.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share the whole code (TS, HTML) for StatusPageComponent?

Comment: If it's relevant to your question, it needs to be here, not on Google Drive. As for your question, I can't see what error you are trying to link, but looking at your code, `item` is undefined when you try to access it outside of the ngFor, which you are doing with `{{item.wtNumber}}` (which is also not a prop in your class!). You also do not have `location` as a prop in your class. If I had to take a wild stab at it, you probably don't see anything in your modal because you are iterating over it and showing values that don't exist (`location`).

Comment: @Rich apologies about that, I cannot upload images as I need 10 reputation to do so.  Maybe this link works? https://photos.app.goo.gl/C6XmGa27K3No7DcE9

I'll post the code snippet of how the code looks when producing the above error

Comment: @robert 
I cannot post the entire code base online as it has sensitive data but here is the majority of the TS and HTML in question https://jsfiddle.net/JSGPL/qj8exrL4/7/

Answer (score 1):

> Any code that I put inside of the div with the *ngFor statement doesn't show up on the modal.

Both `localtion` and `wtNumber` do not appear in your data model.

> If I move it to be the parent container then I get a separate error:

This error is mostly likely related to the method you are using to show the modal.

```
unshippedMaterialModalShow() {
  const modalContainer: any = document.getElementById('self-built-modal');
  modalContainer.style.display='block'; // 'style' here is causing the error
}
```

However, this is not the standard way to show a modal in Angular. Typically, this is done through an *ngIf binding.

TS

```
unshippedMaterialModalShow() {
  this.showModal = true;
}
```

HTML

```
<div
  id="self-built-modal"
  *ngIf="showModal" <!-- toggle 'showModal' variable to show/hide -->
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
  onload="loadUnshippedMaterial(item.wtNumber)"
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have changed the way I show the modal but still no info.  `wtNumber` and `location` both come from the the `this.sageApi.pullReport(unshippedUrlAddon).subscribe` function call inside the `loadUnshippedMaterial` function.

I had mistakenly placed `item.` in front of the `wtNumber` but have since removed it.

If I make a `<div *ngFor="let item of dataModel.unshippedItems; let i = index">` the parent item of my modal then I get no modal showing at all when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is fixed.  We added `unshippedItems: Array<any> = ['loading'];` to the data model so that there is always something within the array before trying to loop over it.  Now when clicking on the button the correct information is shown.

Thank you all for your help and responses!